# Seeking missing element in an array in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `I` with `shape=(10,2)`. I want to probe this array for missing `j=1`. By missing, I mean there are no indices with `j=1`. As is evident from `I`, there are indices with `j=2,3,4,5,6,7`.

For the purpose of notation, in `[0,3]`, `i=0,j=3`.

```
import numpy as np

I=np.array([[0, 3],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 4],
       [4, 5],
       [4, 6],
       [5, 7],
       [6, 7]])
```

The expected output is

```
Missing_j=[1]
```

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how you got the expected output? What do you mean by missing element?

Comment: Also, why do 8..9..10 not count as missing elements?. One last question, how large is your input going to be? Does this need to be a highly optimized algorithm?

Comment: I have edited the post. I am looking for an optimized algorithm which can detect the missing ```j=1```. Other elements with ```j=8,9,10,...``` are not relevant for me right now.

Comment: `if 1 not in I[:,1]: return '1 is missing'` ?

Comment: you could get values in second column and convert to set. And you could generate second `set()` with all values in `range(1, max(second_col)+1)` and later you can use `set2 - set1` to get all missing values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check single index then you can use code from @ArrowRise comment.

```
if 1 not in I[:,1]: return '1 is missing'
```

---

If you want to get all missing indexes then you can use `set()` for this.

You can convert second column to set

```
set1 = set(I[:,1])
```

and generate set with all expected indexes

```
max_j = max(I[:,1])

set2 = set( range(1, max_j+1) )
```

And later you can do

```
missing_j = set2 - set1
```

---

Full working example - I added `[6, 10]` to have more missing indexes.

```
import numpy as np

I = np.array([
    [0, 3],
    [1, 2],
    [1, 4],
    [2, 5],
    [3, 4],
    [4, 5],
    [4, 6],
    [5, 7],
    [6, 7],
    [6, 10],    
])

set1 = set( I[:,1] )

max_j = max(I[:,1])
set2 = set( range(1, max_j+1) )

missing_j = sorted( set2 - set1 )

print( missing_j )
```

Result:

```
[1, 8, 9]
```